Integrating SIP.js or similar library with react-native-webrtc
Please, HELP.
I am trying like for few weeks or months already to make outbound call with sip.js or jssip and react-native-webrtc.
I have stun and turn server from telnyx.
I have default sip.js with API setup like that but with credential data and connection works fine. Getting 200 response all good. Then I am making outbound call to my phone and when I answer or cancel call I get this message:
ERROR  Tue Jul 30 2024 06:37:04 GMT+0100 | sip.SessionDescriptionHandler | SessionDescriptionHandler.setDescription failed - Error: Failed to set remote answer sdp: The m= section with mid='0' is invalid. RTCP-MUX is not enabled when it is required.
ERROR  Tue Jul 30 2024 06:37:04 GMT+0100 | sip.Inviter | Session.setAnswer: SDH setDescription rejected...
ERROR  Tue Jul 30 2024 06:37:04 GMT+0100 | sip.Inviter | Failed to set remote answer sdp: The m= section with mid='0' is invalid. RTCP-MUX is not enabled when it is required.
ERROR  Tue Jul 30 2024 06:37:04 GMT+0100 | sip.Inviter | Failed to set remote answer sdp: The m= section with mid='0' is invalid. RTCP-MUX is not enabled when it is required.
My code is below:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {  registerGlobals  } from "react-native-webrtc";
import { Button, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Inviter, Registerer, SIPExtension, UserAgent } from "sip.js";

// Create user agent instance (caller)
const userAgent = new UserAgent({
  uri: UserAgent.makeURI("sip:alice@example.com"),
  transportOptions: {
    server: "wss://sip.example.com"
  },
});

  registerGlobals()

// Connect the user agent
userAgent.start().then(() => {

  // Set target destination (callee)
  const target = UserAgent.makeURI("sip:bob@example.com");
  if (!target) {
    throw new Error("Failed to create target URI.");
  }

  // Create a user agent client to establish a session
  const inviter = new Inviter(userAgent, target, {
    sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions: {
      constraints: { audio: true, video: false }
    }
  });

  // Handle outgoing session state changes
  inviter.stateChange.addListener((newState) => {
    switch (newState) {
      case SessionState.Establishing:
        // Session is establishing
        break;
      case SessionState.Established:
        // Session has been established
        break;
      case SessionState.Terminated:
        // Session has terminated
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  // Send initial INVITE request
  inviter.invite()
    .then(() => {
      // INVITE sent
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      // INVITE did not send
    });

});


I tried most stuff from internet and guides.

have you tried jssip instead of sip.js?

yes, I tried jssip. And always getting bad media description
